# Wordpress: How do I get the current name of my page

Tags: php, wordpress

If my current url is www.example.com/thank-you, how do I echo out the page name in a wordpress way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WordPress Way:**

```
echo $post->post_name;
```

**Normal Way:** (Should work in WP too)

```
echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Comment: I doubt `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` would return anything that looks like `www.example.com/thank-you` or `/thank-you`